# Enable Submit button only if a value changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-5

**Scenario :**

I have a form which may or may not have value. Initially, the submit button will be disabled. If I change anything in the form element, I need to enable the submit button. But if I change a name textbox which has value "SAM" to "SAM2", which enables the submit button, but if i change the name value again to its original value "SAM", then its considered untouched and the submit button should be disabled.

**Current Implementation :**

Since at the moment, I have used change event to enable the submit button, but if i revert the value back, the button is still enabled.

**Code:**

**HTML:**

```
<form id="specgeneralform">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="spec-detail-outsource">Outsource</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OutSource, outsourcelistItems, "Please Select", new { @id = "spec-detail-outsource" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 lsc-optional-hide" id="vendor-block">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="spec-detail-vendors">Vendor</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.VendorID, new SelectList(Model.listVendors, "VendorID", "VendorName"), "Please Select", new { @id = "spec-detail-vendors" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 lsc-optional-hide" id="plant-block">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="spec-detail-plant">Plant</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PlantID, new SelectList(Model.listPlants, "PlantID", "PlantName"), "Please Select", new { @id = "spec-detail-plant" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 lsc-optional-hide" id="dsc-block">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="spec-detail-dsclocation">DSC Location</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DscLocationID, new SelectList(Model.listDSCLocations, "PlantID", "PlantName"), "Please Select", new { @id = "spec-detail-dsclocation" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DscLocationID)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 lsc-optional-hide" id="cost-block">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="spec-detail-cost">Cost</label>
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
                </div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Cost, new { @class = "form-control small" })
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CostUOM, costuomlistItems, "Please Select", new { @id = "spec-detail-unit" })

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="comment">Comments</label>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.BuyerComments, new { @class = "form-control" })
            <label id="BuyerComments-error" class="error invalid-feedback" for="BuyerComments">Comments must not be more than 1000 characters</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
    <div class="col-12">
        <button id="spec-detail-general-save" type="button" class="btn lsc-btn-primary float-right" disabled="disabled">SAVE CHANGES</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$(":input").change(function () {

    if ($("#specgeneralform").valid()) {
        unsaved = true;
        $("#spec-detail-general-save").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
        unsaved = false;
        $("#spec-detail-general-save").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Please advise any best way to do it?

**UPDATE #1**

I have tried out @Takit-Isy solution, It worked out for every elements except this one

```
<tr>
   <td>Spec Confirmed:</td>
   <td>
      <label class="switch">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.SpecConfirmed)
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>MDM Override:</td>
        <td>
           <label class="switch">
             @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsOverride)
             <span class="slider round"></span>
           </label>
         </td>
      </tr>
```

so I have styled the checkbox like this one, which is not working, but rest are working perfect.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to enhance Keith's answer, here is what I'll do:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input, select");
for (const el of inputs){
  el.oldValue = el.value + el.checked;
}

// Declares function and call it directly
var setEnabled;
(setEnabled = function() {
  var e = true;
  for (const el of inputs) {
    if (el.oldValue !== (el.value + el.checked)) {
      e = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  document.querySelector("button").disabled = e;
})();

document.oninput = setEnabled;
document.onchange = setEnabled;
```

```html
<form>
  input 1: <input value="one"><br>
  input 2: <input value="two"><br>
  select 1:
  <select>
    <option>Bla1</option>
    <option>Bla2</option>
    <option>Bla3</option>
  </select><br>
  Checkbox 1: <input type="checkbox"><br>
  Checkbox 2: <input type="checkbox" checked><br>
  <button action="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

I know the way of declaring the function to call it directly after creation is tricky, but, that's the way and it works fine!…

I hope it helps.

Comment: Is this code only for input text? or for select/dropdown?

Comment: @RanjithVaradan I added a `select` in the snippet, I only needed to add `select` in the `querySelectorAll()` to make it work with it.

Comment: Yes it works perfect except checkbox. any idea for checkbox?

Comment: @RanjithVaradan I've just added checkboxes to the snippet.

Comment: It should work if the objects inserted by "mvc" are actually checkboxes.

Comment: const won't work with IE so it can lead to browser compatibility issues.

Comment: @dnxit Many things won't work with IE… In that specific case, it wouldn't be so difficult to change it to `var`.

Comment: @TakitIsy I tried changing just const to var but it didn't work after that modification so I had to rewrite it with jquery and used some of your code.

Comment: @dnxit Well, it's working if I edit my snippet and change all the `const` to `var`, so maybe the issue lies somewhere in your page/code. Did you make some debugging or have an error?

Answer (score 2):

As you may have dynamic initial values I suggest a general way. Set the intial value of all inputs in a data attribute so you can compare any change against the initial values:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(":input").each(function(){
        $(this).data("initial",$(this).val());
     })
})

$(":input").change(function () {

    if ($("#specgeneralform").valid() && $(this).val() != $(this).data("initial")) {

        unsaved = true;
        $("#spec-detail-general-save").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else {
        unsaved = false;
        $("#spec-detail-general-save").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: I put `:input` inside a loop to set their initial values. please check again.

Answer (score 1):

Without using jQuery, here is a simple method..

test: Change input 1, from `one`, and back again.. Do same for input 2..

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

function saveCurrent() {
  for (const el of inputs) el.oldValue = el.value;
}

function setEnabled() {
  var e = false;
  for (const el of inputs) {
    if (el.oldValue !== el.value) {
      e = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  document.querySelector("button").disabled = !e;
}

document.addEventListener("input", setEnabled);

saveCurrent();
setEnabled();
```

```html
<form>
  input 1: <input value="one"><br>
  input 2: <input value="two"><br>
  <button action="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

On change, iterate through the `input`s and check that all inputs are blank (or default - like `'SAM'`). If so, then disable the button; else, enable the button. Hard to post exactly how to iterate without seeing the content of the HTML form though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for IE compatible then use below

Modified Takit Isy's version who borrowed it from Keith (Thanks guys).

```
   $(document).ready(function () {    
         trackInputs(); 
    });

    var controls = $('form').find(':input');
    var controlValues = [];
    $(controls).each(function (i, element) {
        var ctrl = [element.id, element.value + element.checked]
        controlValues.push(ctrl);
    });
    function trackInputs() {
      var disabled = true;
        $(controlValues).each(function (i, element) {
            if (element[0] != "") {
                var ctr = $("#" + element[0]);
                if ($(ctr).val() + $(ctr).prop( "checked" ) !== element[1]) {
                    disabled = false;
                }
            }
        });
        var submitButton = document.querySelector("[type=submit]");
        if (submitButton != null)
        {
            submitButton.disabled = disabled;
        }
    };
    document.oninput = trackInputs;
    document.onchange = trackInputs;
```